# SortSite Text Not Allowed message

Tags: html, w3c

I am using SortSite to check my website for accessibility.  I have one error I just cannot clear and I was hoping to get more eyes on it to see if anyone can tell me what is wrong...  the error only says Text Not Allowed... anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks!

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="obscure" id="Communicating+With+Young+Children_category">Communicating With Young Children</span><a href="p_module_categories.php?id_division=d01&amp;id_category=001&amp;id_module=001&amp;page=1" aria-label="Communicating+With+Young+Children_category">Communicating With Young Children</a></li>
  <li><span class="obscure" id="Considering+Parenthood_category">Considering Parenthood</span><a href="p_module_categories.php?id_division=d01&amp;id_category=002&amp;id_module=001&amp;page=1" aria-label="Considering+Parenthood_category">Considering Parenthood</a></li>
  <li><span class="obscure" id="Children%27s+Self-Esteem_category">Children's Self-Esteem</span><a href="p_module_categories.php?id_division=d01&amp;id_category=003&amp;id_module=001&amp;page=1" aria-label="Children%27s+Self-Esteem_category">Children's Self-Esteem</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your HTML against the HTML 5 validator at [html5.validator.nu](https://html5.validator.nu/) like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><span class="obscure" id="Communicating+With+Young+Children_category">Communicating With Young Children</span><a href="p_module_categories.php?id_division=d01&amp;id_category=001&amp;id_module=001&amp;page=1" aria-label="Communicating+With+Young+Children_category">Communicating With Young Children</a></li>
  <li><span class="obscure" id="Considering+Parenthood_category">Considering Parenthood</span><a href="p_module_categories.php?id_division=d01&amp;id_category=002&amp;id_module=001&amp;page=1" aria-label="Considering+Parenthood_category">Considering Parenthood</a></li>
  <li><span class="obscure" id="Children%27s+Self-Esteem_category">Children's Self-Esteem</span><a href="p_module_categories.php?id_division=d01&amp;id_category=003&amp;id_module=001&amp;page=1" aria-label="Children%27s+Self-Esteem_category">Children's Self-Esteem</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Results

> The document is valid HTML5 + ARIA + SVG 1.1 + MathML 2.0

This leads me to believe that sortSite complains because of the `id` attribute of your `span` element is in conflict with the HTML 4 rules.

[HTML 4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) requires the following for the `id` attribute.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[HTML 5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/elements.html#the-id-attribute) only requires that

> The value must not contain any space characters.

Comment: Thank you!!!  That is very helpful, I have been working on getting this site compliant for a couple of weeks now and this has been a block for me - I appreciate your input!! :)